# In Matlab why does cellfun(@size, x) not require UniformOutput False for non scalar values?

Tags: matlab

In Matlab you can do the following

```
x = {1:4, rand(3,3,3), 3};
[a, b, c] = cellfun(@size, x);
```

The above though not scalar output, does not require UniformOutput to be false.

If instead I have

```
x = {1:4, rand(3,3,3), 3};
[a,b,c] = cellfun(@(my_dummy_fun) [1, 2, 3], x);  % GIVES ERROR
```

I get an error.  How is this different than @size?  Is there a way to get the same behavior for the custom function as for size?

thanks!

Comment: Interesting. It appears this has something to do with the fact that `size`returns a variable number of outputs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You where confused by size. Size allows a single output (vector) or multiple output arguments.

```
%three outputs
[a,b,c]=size(rand(3,3,3))
%one output
[x]=size(rand(3,3,3))
```

where x =[a,b,c]

You are successfully using size with three output arguments, but your function handle has only one output argument (which is a vector).

I don't know any possible syntax to directly define a anonymous function with multiple output arguments. To work around this, I wrote this small wrapper function:

```
function varargout=vec2nargout(in)
varargout=mat2cell(in(:),ones(1,nargout));
end
```

It allows:

```
[a,b,c] = cellfun(@(my_dummy_fun)vec2nargout([1,2,3]), x);
```

Comment: If the output of my dummy function is interpreted as one output of a vector, how can I instead have it interpreted as multiple outputs?

Comment: You can make anonymous functions with multiple output arguments using `deal`. For example, `f = @(x)deal(x.^2,x.^3)`. Call with `[a,b]=f(2)` to get both, or use `[a,~]=f(2)` or `[~,b]=f(2)` to get only one of the outputs. This doesn't of course get you a *variable* number of output arguments - for that, you need to define a function with `varargout` as you suggested.